# CMD cannot "read" my phones /etc/hosts file when editing it via adb

Tags: adb, root-access, hosts

I have to configure my /etc/hosts file on my rooted device(Lineage OS). I can see the content with cat but when I try to open it with vim/nano/vi I only get these questionmark boxes. Screenshot: https://puu.sh/y6WzY/38fcef5594.png

I also tried modifying it in any possible way but this seems like the only one where I actually can get read/write permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it via pulling it on my pc and pushing it back on my phone:

```
adb pull /system/etc/hosts F:\hosts # then edit it with notepad, etc
adb push F:\hosts /system/etc/      # pushing it back on my phone
```